# PyQt different windows during a script

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I developed a script for pcba testing and it works fine.
Now I want to implement a very simple flow like this:

- Window popup just to let the user start the test
- Run the test without any window (the terminal is just fine)
- Window popup to show pass/fail result of the test

I already developed the two windows in two other .py files, which run without any problems when "standalone".

If I implement these two within the script, the first appears normally, but the second opens and closes istantly.

Without being too complicated, the test function is defined in `serial.py`, the first window in `infoBox.py` and the final window in `getResult.py`.

Inside the `serial.py` I tried:

```
import infoBox
import getResult

[...]

def work():
   [...]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app1 = QApplication([])
    win1 = infoBox.infoBox("""Turn on 24V alim and press OK.""")
    win1.show()
    app.exec()

    [...]
    work()
    [...]

    app2 = QApplication([])
    generateWindow(esiti=lst_esiti, info=lst_info) # <------- this calls getResult.getResult class and .show() the widget
    win2 = getResult.getResult(lst_esito=lst_esiti, lst_info=lst_info)
    win2.show()
    app.exec()
```

So, when `serial.py` is lounched by terminal, the infoBox instance appears, the work() function does what it has to, and the getResult instance (which has a OK button to be closed) is instantly closed.

Maybe the error is the definition of two QApplication? I tried a lot but I'm not able to manage it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came up with this.
It was easier than expected...

Solved opening a unique QApplication and call app.exec() after each subclass calling.